# Dynamic programming and Divide and conquer approach

Tags: dynamic-programming

How does Dynamic Programming differ from Divide and conquer approach for solving problems?
Can anyone explain the essential idea of Dynamic Programming.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is probably not a research level question: better ask it on [cs.se].

Comment: The difference is memoization. In addition to Tim's online lectures, another good resource is Jeff Erickson's lecture notes: http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/05-dynprog.pdf

Comment: Please see [about] and [help/on-topic] for information about the scope of [cstheory.se]. Remember that there is also [cs.se] which has a broader scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is available online

- You can read their description and comparisons on wikipedia:

  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm
  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming
- You can watch Tim Roughgarden's videos about these two topics:

  - http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/CoursePage.php?course=IntroToAlgorithms